# Unsure of how to proceed through Trace Property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, trace

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to derive the following from Andrew Ng's CS229 lecture notes.

$$\nabla_A \textrm{Tr } ABA^{T}C = CAB + C^TAB^T $$

where $\textrm{Tr }$ is the trace operator of a matrix. This is from his section on matrix derivatives in his [lecture notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf).

Comment: use the definition and write down the matrix multiplication elementwise with sums

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a quadratic function of a single variable $(A)$, consider a function that is linear in two variables $(X,Y)$ and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}(XBYC) \cr
d\phi
 &= {\rm tr}(BYC\,dX + CXB\,dY)) \cr
 &= C^TY^TB^T:dX + CXB:dY^T \cr
}$$
Now make the substitutions $(X,Y)\rightarrow(A,A^T)$
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}(ABA^TC) \cr
d\phi &= C^TAB^T:dA + CAB:dA \cr
\nabla_A\phi &= C^TAB^T + CAB \cr
}$$